# Relaxing multiple edges in a graph (Dijkstra's)

Tags: algorithm, graph, python-2.x, shortest-path, dijkstra

I recently ran into a [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach) where I have to find the shortest path between two nodes in an undirected weighted multigraph. I am new to multigraphs so the concept of multiple edges is still new to me. I used Dijkstra's and initially just considered the edge which had the least weight and disregarded all other multiple edges between a given pair of nodes. But to my surprise, the algorithm wasn't producing the right results. It wasn't until I considered all of the multiple edges in a giver pair of nodes and relaxed them accordingly that I was able to find the optimal answer. How come I had to include all of the multiple edges? Doesn't it make more sense to just take the edge with the least weight?  Thanks in advance!

Here is my initial implementation (Python 2.7)

```
from heapq import heappop,heappush
import sys

inf = float('inf')
def relax(Weight,u,v,Dist):
    d = Dist.get(u,inf) + Weight
    if d < Dist.get(v,inf):
        Dist[v] = d

def dijkstra(g,s):
    Dist,visited,priority_q = {s:0},set(),[(0,s)]
    while priority_q:
        _,u = heappop(priority_q)
        if u in visited: continue
        visited.add(u)
        for i in g[u]:
            relax(g[u][i],u,i,Dist)
            heappush(priority_q,(Dist[i],i))
    return Dist 

T = input()
for i in xrange(T):
    N,M = map(int,raw_input().split())
    graph = {k:{} for k in xrange(1,N+1)}
    for j in xrange(M):
        a,b,cost = map(int,raw_input().split())
        try:
            graph[a][b] = min(cost,g[a][b])
            graph[b][a] = min(cost,g[b][a])
        except KeyError:
            graph[a][b] = cost
            graph[b][a] = cost
    start = input()
    output, output_str = dijkstra(graph,start),[]
    for j in graph:
        if j!=start:
            try:
                output_str.append(str(output[j]))
            except KeyError:
                output_str.append('-1')
    print " ".join(output_str).rstrip()
```

And here is my final implementation. I only posted a part of it because everything else is the same.

```
'''EVERYTHING ABOVE IS THE SAME'''

def dijkstra(g,s):
    Dist,visited,priority_q = {s:0},set(),[(0,s)]
    while priority_q:
        _,u = heappop(priority_q)
        if u in visited: continue
        visited.add(u)
        for i in g[u]:
            if g[u][i]:
                for k in g[u][i]:
                    relax(k,u,i,D)
                    heappush(priority_q,(D[i],i))
    return Dist 

T = input()
for i in xrange(T):
    N,M = map(int,raw_input().split())
    graph = {k:{j:[] for j in xrange(1,N+1) if j!=k} for k in xrange(1,N+1)}
    for j in xrange(M):
        a,b,cost = map(int,raw_input().split())
        graph[a][b].append(cost)
        graph[b][a].append(cost)

''' EVERYTHING BELOW IS THE SAME '''
```

Comment: Can you show an example of a graph where you got the wrong results and the implementation that produced those results, please?

Comment: I made some changes to the question, hopefully it's more specific now. I couldn't really come up with a small test case of my own that would give me errors though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _relax_ in this context?

Comment: @Codor Setting a lower upper bound for a given node.

Comment: Your initial implementation passes all the HackerRank tests except the last one, where it times out. Were you wondering about the timeout, or did you maybe test the wrong code?